# How to merge cell Dynamically using igx-grid in angular

Tags: angular, igx-grid

Grid should look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xrmzG.png)

I don't know how to do?

Will someone explain to mi

I am new in igx-grid

Comment: What have you tried, and why didn't it work?

Comment: sorry for let replay

 <igx-column
        *ngFor="let col of columns"
        [field]="col.field"
        [width]="col.innerWidth"
        [header]="col.header"
       >
 </igx-column>

This is my code. I am getting data dynamically from data source.

Comment: If you are just starting your jorney with the igx-grid and the Ignite UI for Angular libtary, my recomendation is to check out the dev documentation. It provides information on how to achieve different things from beginner to advanced level.

https://www.infragistics.com/products/ignite-ui-angular/angular/components/grid/grid

It will also help you gain better understanding of the product and what type of knowledge you lack.